# How to add global container fo all my actions using layout block magento2

Tags: magento2, blocks

i want to add a global select like 'Select one option' contains my all actions 'Renew' and 'View' ,
can anyone tell me how to do that ?

This is my code for now I have done some effort but 'Select one option' still not showing?

```
$this->addColumn(
                'action',
                [
                    'header' => 'Action',
                    'filter' => false,
                    'sortable' => false,
                    'width' => '100px',
                    'renderer' => \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Reorder\Renderer\Action::class
                ]
            );
```

```
public function render(\Magento\Framework\DataObject $row)
    {
        $this->_actions = [];
        if ($this->_salesReorder->canReorder($row->getId())) {
            $tbltofill = [];
            $reorderAction = [
                'view' => [
                    'href' => $this->getUrl('sales/order/view', ['order_id' => $row->getId()]),
                    'label' => __('View'),
                ],
                'renew' => [
                    'href' => $this->getUrl('sales/order_create/reorder', ['order_id' => $row->getId()]),
                    'label' => __('Renew'),
                ]
            ];
            $tbltofill['Select one option'] = $reorderAction;
            $this->addToActions($tbltofill);
        }
        $this->_eventManager->dispatch(
            'adminhtml_customer_orders_add_action_renderer',
            ['renderer' => $this, 'row' => $row]
        );
        return $this->_actionsToHtml();
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Try this to replace and remove your renderer function

```
    $this->addColumn(
        'action',
        [
            'header' => __('Action'),
            'type' => 'action',
            'getter' => 'getId',
            'actions' => [
                [
                    'caption' => __('View'),
                    'url' => [
                        'base' => 'sales/order/view'
                    ],
                    'field' => 'order_id'
                ],
                [
                    'caption' => __('Renew'),
                    'url' => [
                        'base' => 'sales/order_create/reorder'
                    ],
                    'field' => 'order_id'
                ]
            ],
            'filter' => false,
            'sortable' => false,
            'index' => 'stores',
            'header_css_class' => 'col-action',
            'column_css_class' => 'col-action'
        ]
    );
```

Comment: than you , but i render the actions from this class ==> 'renderer' => \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Reorder\Renderer\Action::class , not just from the addColumn

Comment: remove this class replace this above code and check and update me.

Comment: in above code we not need this class  \Magento\Sales\Block\Adminhtml\Reorder\Renderer\Action::class

Comment: but in my case i need it , should i change something in the "public function render" above?

Comment: Using above code you don't need to use "public function render"